# Python Twistd MySQL - Get Updated Row id (not inserting)

Tags: python, mysql, twisted

Python, Twistd and SO newbie.

I am writing a program that organises seating across multiple rooms.  I have only included related columns from the tables below.

Basic Mysql tables

Table

- id

Seat

- id
- table_id
- name

Card

- seat_id

The `Seat` and `Table` tables are pre-populated with the 'name' columns initially NULL.

**Stage One**

I want to update a seat's name by finding the first available seat given a group of table ids.

**Stage Two**

I want to be able to get the updated row id from Stage One (because I don't already know this) to add to the `Card` table.  Names can be assigned to more than one seat so I can't just find a seat that matches a name.

I can do Stage One but have no idea how to do Stage Two because `lastrowid` only works for inserts not updates.

Any help would be appreciated.

Using twisted.enterprise.adbapi if that helps.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to accomplish this is to first make a select for the id (or ids) of the row/rows you want to update, then update the row with a WHERE condition matching the id of the item to update. That way you are certain that you only updated the specific item.

An UPDATE statement can update multiple rows that matches your criteria. That is why you cannot request the last updated id by using a built in function.

Comment: Thanks. 

I think I tried that but I may have had the query wrong (should have posted here).

I ended up just redesigning the tables and relationships which was a real pain but luckily it was still very early stages.